# How can i call Shopify's API to create a new product?

Tags: api, salesforce, shopify

I need to call Shopify's API's to create a new product or get details of existing products. How can i do this. Basically how to make a connection of salesforce with shopify?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify provide [REST API](https://help.shopify.com/api), so you need to use it for integration with your Salesforce solution. On Salesforce side you need to do few steps for implementation of connection.

Usual you need to make a post/get requests to some URL you would do the following.

**Add your domain under Remote Site Settings**

To send an outbound calls (POST/GET requests) from Apex in Salesforce, you need to add the domain to Remote Site Settings in setup.

**Create and send the request in your APEX controller**

For instance, for POST request you need to implement something like this

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();

req.setEndpoint('https://someurl.com/api');
req.setMethod('POST');

//these parts of the POST you may want to customize
req.setCompressed(false);
req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  

try {
    res = http.send(req);
} catch(System.CalloutException e) {
    System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
}
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

For more information take a look on Salesforce documentation:

[Apex Web Services and Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts)

[HttpRequest Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm)

[HttpResponse Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I just recently actually managed to develop what (I think) you are looking for in PHP and since i had plenty trouble finding all the info I actually went ahead and created an account just to answer this for you :)

my PHP code is as follows:

```
//Modify these
  $API_KEY = 'yourAPIkey';
 $SECRET = 'yourAPIsercer(password)';
  $TOKEN = 'zzz';
  $STORE_URL = 'yourstore.myshopify.com';

    $url = 'https://' . $API_KEY . ':' . $SECRET . '@' . $STORE_URL . '/admin/products.xml';

$xmlsrc = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<product>
<title>TITLEH!!!</title>
<body-html>asdasdfda</body-html>
<product-type>Photoshop</product-type>
<variants type="array">
    <variant>
        <price>3.00</price>
        <inventory-quantity>7</inventory-quantity>
    </variant>
</variants>
<vendor>JLH</vendor>
</product>
XML;

    $session = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlsrc); 
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml', 'Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

if(ereg("^(https)",$url)) curl_setopt($session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);

$result = curl_exec($session);

    curl_close($session);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $doc->formatOutput = true;
    $doc->loadXML($result);
    echo $doc->saveXML();
```

I believe it's straightforward enough.
It's also quite easy to modify it for different actions once you get the hang of it...
I got alot of useful info from this thread: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/php-api-example-26017

and the rest i deducted from the shopify API reference: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product
(note that API reference uses json examples and i am working with XML)

I hope this helps you.